# What are the logical underpinnings of the epsilon- delta definition of limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having trouble getting my head around the epsilon-delta defintion of limits. I learned about conditional statements and I know that in order for a conditional to be true , one of the following cases have to hold

- both antecedent and consequent are true, ***or***
- both are false, ***or***
- the consequent is true and antecedent is false.

Now in proving the definition of a limit say
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} x^2 + x -11 = 9 $$
which case do we prove? Is it the same for every limit or are different limits proved by different cases?

How does the concept of conditional truth-tables relate to this definition?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If antecedent is false then consequent is irrelevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're proving that $P\implies Q$, for some statements $P$ and $Q$, you **don't care** which of these 
$$\underbrace{P\textsf{ true},\;Q\textsf{ true}}_{\large P\land Q}\qquad\qquad \underbrace{P\textsf{ false},\;Q\textsf{ true}}_{\large (\lnot P)\land Q}\qquad\qquad \underbrace{P\textsf{ false},\;Q\textsf{ false}}_{\large (\lnot P)\land(\lnot Q)}$$
is true. Your only task is to prove that
$$\underbrace{P\textsf{ true},\;Q\textsf{ false}}_{\large P\land(\lnot Q)}$$
is false. In other words, these statements are logically equivalent:
$$(P\implies Q)\iff\lnot(P\land(\lnot Q))$$

---

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, and real numbers $a,L\in\mathbb{R}$, the **meaning** of the statement
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$$
is that
$$\textsf{for any }\epsilon>0,\textsf{ there exists some }\delta>0\textsf{ such that for all }x\in\mathbb{R},\\
|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
Let's take a look at your example of
$$\lim_{x\to 4}x^2+x-11=9$$
so $\,a=4$, $\,L=9$, $\,f(x)=x^2+x-11$. If $\epsilon=1$, then you want to find a $\delta>0$ such that
$$\textsf{for all }x\in\mathbb{R},\;\;|x-4|<\delta\implies|x^2+x-11-9|<1$$
An example of such a $\delta$ would be $\delta=\frac{1}{10}$. In order to **prove** that
$$\textsf{for all }x\in\mathbb{R},\;\;|x-4|<\tfrac{1}{10}\implies|x^2+x-20|<1$$
all we care about is proving that there is no $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$|x-4|<\tfrac{1}{10}\textsf{ true},\;|x^2+x-20|<1\textsf{ false}$$
For example,
$$|5-4|<\tfrac{1}{10}\textsf{ false},\;|5^2+5-20|<1\textsf{ false}\qquad\quad \textsf{great! }\checkmark$$
$$|4.109-4|<\tfrac{1}{10}\textsf{ false},\;|(4.109)^2+(4.109)-20|<1\textsf{ true}\qquad\quad \textsf{great! }\checkmark$$
$$|4.05-4|<\tfrac{1}{10}\textsf{ true},\;|(4.05)^2+(4.05)-20|<1\textsf{ true}\qquad\quad \textsf{great! }\checkmark$$

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure we are on the same page, let me write out that conditional:

For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$

$$
|x - 4| < \delta \implies |(x^2 + x - 11) - 9| < \epsilon\\
$$

Note that the conditional appears AFTER you choose $\epsilon$, $\delta$, and $x$. For any choice of $\epsilon$, there needs to be some choice for $\delta$, such that for any choice of $x$, the conditional is true.

Which of those three cases holds will depend on the $\epsilon$, $\delta$ and $x$ you choose!

Say you take a small $\epsilon$, choose a $\delta$ small enough for the $\epsilon$, and take an $x$ that is very far from 4 (like 100 or something). Then:

$$
|x - 4| > \delta
$$

$$
|(x^2 + x - 11) - 9| > \epsilon
$$

So the antecedant is false, the consequent is false, and the conditional is true.

Now say you take an $x$ that is very far from 4, but very close to -5. Then:

$$
|x - 4| > \delta
$$
$$
|(x^2 + x - 11) - 9| < \epsilon
$$

(Because -5 is the other solution to the equation $x^2 + x - 11 = 9$.)

So the antecedant is false, the consequent is true, and the conditional is true.

Finally, say you take an $x$ that is very close to 4. Then:

$$
|x - 4| < \delta
$$
$$
|(x^2 + x - 11) - 9| < \epsilon
$$

So the antecedant and consequent are both true, and the conditional is true.

So the answer is: you use all three cases for every problem! Which one holds depends on which $x$ you are looking at.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question!

Strictly speaking, there is a logical implication here. But once you understand *that we only care about one case*, your job becomes much easier (and less confusing). Why do we only care about one case?

Another way to look at the statement "$Q$, whenever $P$" (equivalently, "If $P$, then $Q$") is that the statement is true if

- Both $P$ and $Q$ are true, or if
- $P$ (the antecedent) is false.

The latter case, when the antecedent is false, we often say that the statement "$Q$, whenever $P$" is *vacuously* true (and I think of it as "true by a technicality", or "true by default"). It's similar to the statement "If I go to the store, I'll bring you something". You wouldn't consider me a liar if I don't go to the store (regardless of whether I've brought you anything), would you? It's essentially the same kind of "true by a technicality." If I don't go to the store, then you don't even need to ask "Have you brought me anything?" because I *technically* couldn't possibly have lied to you.

---

**Aside:** My thoughts are that the logic we use in calculus isn't really the same kind of logic that's done in a purely logical setting; at least, we don't have the same goals. We really don't care about implications with false antecedents because we're only interested in *using* implications (and properties defined with implications, like continuity) to deduce things. For that we need [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens), which requires our antecedents to be true.

For this reason, I think a truth table will *generally* be nearly useless in a calculus setting.

---

So, when confronted with the task of showing that

> for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $\lvert f(x) - 9 \rvert < \epsilon$ whenever $\lvert x - 4 \rvert < \delta$,

we do a few things:

1. Pick a generic $\epsilon > 0$.
2. Find some $\delta > 0$ so that when we assume $\lvert x - 4 \rvert < \delta$, we can show that $\lvert f(x) - 9 \rvert < \epsilon$.

Step 2. is where all the work happens. It usually involves using some unknown $\delta$, assuming $\lvert x - 4 \rvert < \delta$, and seeing what kind of relationship we can derive, algebraically, between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

(Notice that I said "we assume $\lvert x - 4 \rvert < \delta$". This goes back to the fact that, if $\lvert x - 4 \rvert \nless \delta$, then our antecedent is false, and the "$Q$, whenever $P$" statement involving the two inequalities is true by default -- there's literally nothing to show, so we don't even bother talking about it.)

Once we have our $\delta$, actually showing that $\lvert f(x) - 9 \rvert < \epsilon$ using our $\delta$ and $x$ such that $\lvert x - 4 \rvert < \delta$ can happen almost as if by magic: We generally don't even need to say *how* we found such a $\delta$ (although we had to go through the algebra in step 2. to do so), only that we've found one, and shown that it works.